# Vertical centering of multi-line cstatic text in MFC

Tags: mfc, vertical-alignment, multiline

**How can one make a `CStatic` with text auto-wrap (multiline) which vertically centeres the result in the control's rectangle?**

The problem I'm trying to solve is this: I have a `CStatic` control next to a `CComboBox` which updates information text depending on the choice. This text can be either short or long, requiring the `CStatic` to sometimes use multi-lines, and sometimes not.  I want the info-text be vertically center-aligned with the `CComboBox`.

Now here is the problem:

- If I make the `CStatic` only 1 textline high, it looks good for 1-line texts, but multi-lines do not fit and are not displayed.
- If I make the `CStatic` higher to fit 2 lines, it looks good for long texts (with 2 lines), but 1-line-texts are shifted upwards, as the `CStatic` aligns the text on the top. A `CStatic` with the behavior mentioned in the question would solve this...

If I can't easily get a vertically centered `CStatic` multi-line control, the alternative would be to resize the control rect depending on the amount of text in it. But in this case I have a different problem:

**How can I programatically find out how many lines a text will need in a `CStatic` of specific width?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't vcenter multi-line text in a `CStatic`.

Your next question has a solution but it's a bit of a pain to use. What you do is you use `CDC::DrawTextEx` with the `DT_CALCRECT` flag to get the size (in pixels) of the text you want to format. By dividing that by the height of a line of text (given in the font info you can get from the `DC`, plus some spacing which I'm not sure of how much that is - presumably it's a fixed amount, I don't think you can specify line spacing with `DrawText`), you will get (an approximation of) the number of lines you will get. You can then resize the control rect.

Come to think of it, you are probably better off not converting to lines and just resize your control to the extent you get from `DrawTextEx` :)

Things like this usually require some experimentation to get exactly right, and sometimes behave differently between OS versions. Proceed with caution.

Comment: What about adding `SS_CENTERIMAGE` to the `dwStyle` in the `Create()` call?  That just worked for me under MS Windows 7.

Comment: The question was about multi-line text. When you apply SS_CENTERIMAGE, word wrap doesn't work any more. I just tested it on VS2008 / WinXP and it has this behavior. Did you try with multi-line text? I'll update my answer regardless.

Comment: Oops...indeed, I wasn't using multi-line text.  My bad.

Comment: ulatekt, thank you! SS_CENTERIMAGE centers purfectly with single-line text.